# Variable number of inputs with Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-forms

Currently I'm making a platform based on chamilo and I'm stuck because a template´s form for tests. The reason is becasuse I have to adquire de data from the form and organized to send througth the chamilo api rest. Currently This form is made of 6 static hidden inputs, but the real problem is the other inputs that are generate in function of the number of questions.
In the forms.py file I defined a class for this form but only with 6 inputs but I don´t know how to handle the variable inputs from the tests answers because the tests have different number of questions and answers

```
class Ejercicios(forms.Form):
    c_id = forms.CharField()
    lp_id = forms.CharField()
    item_id = forms.CharField()
    item_viewId = forms.CharField()
    exe_id = forms.CharField()
    time = forms.CharField()
```

My class in forms.py look like this, how can I add different number of extra forms dynamically?

Comment: maybe Django formset will help

Comment: @c.grey How's that? I'm noob in django

Comment: read this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/formsets/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [**JSONField**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#jsonfield) for your class Model:

> A field for storing JSON encoded data. In Python the data is
> represented in its Python native format: dictionaries, lists, strings,
> numbers, booleans and None.

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField

class Ejercicios(models.Model):
    ...
    data = JSONField(default=dict)
    ...
```

For **Django 3.1 and greater** use **`django.db.models.JSONField`** instead.

See also [**Querying JSONField**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#querying-jsonfield)

Comment: Thanks It worked for me, only needed to modify the template

Comment: @JuanDavidPolo, happy to help 